# How to override default params in object passed into function?

Tags: javascript, default-parameters

A defaultOptions objects with some params is created.

```
const defaultOptions =  {
  name: 'Adrian',
  city: 'Paris',
  job: 'Designer',
}
```

This function creates a sentence from the params.

```
function makeSentence(defaultOptions) {
  console.log('My name is ' + defaultOptions.name + ' and I come from ' + defaultOptions.city + ' and I am a ' + defaultOptions.job + '.');
}
```

When called with defaultOptions it logs to the console as follows:

```
makeSentence(defaultOptions);
// My name is Adrian and I come from Paris and I am a Designer.
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to override some of the params to get a result like:

```
makeSentence(defaultOptions, 'Michael');
// My name is Michael and I come from Paris and I am a Designer.
```

**EDIT: Success with modification of Patrick Roberts' and Anamul Hasan's answers**

defaultOptions object remains the same.
Function to create a sentence from params becomes:

```
function makeSentence(defaultOptions) {
  var options = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, options);
  console.log('My name is ' + options.name + ' and I come from ' + options.city + ' and I am a ' + options.job + '.');
}
```

To override default params:

```
makeSentence({name: 'Michael'}); // overrides only the name attr.
```

Comment: It's not clear what specifically you are looking for...  why don't you copy the defaultParams object and then modify the copy before passing it to your makeSentence() method?

Comment: That edit will not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. This won't override defaultOptions, instead it will copy the value and replace it.

```
makeSentence(Object.assign({},defaultOptions,{name:"Michael"}))
```

Comment: Slight modification but your answer works:
`makeSentence(Object.assign(defaultOptions, {name:"Michael"}));`

However, I was hoping to avoid having to put Object.assign() into the function call and have it be handled in the function itself if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this using ES6 default parameters:

```js
const defaultOptions = {
  name: 'Adrian',
  city: 'Paris',
  job: 'Designer'
}

const makeSentence = function makeSentence(name = this.name, city = this.city, job = this.job) {
  console.log('My name is ' + name + ' and I come from ' + city + ' and I am a ' + job + '.')
}.bind(defaultOptions)

makeSentence()
makeSentence('Michael')
makeSentence('Michael', 'London')
makeSentence('Michael', 'London', 'Programmer')
```

However, I'd argue it would be more intuitive to do this, almost like default named parameters:

```js
const defaultOptions = {
  name: 'Adrian',
  city: 'Paris',
  job: 'Designer'
}

const makeSentence = function makeSentence({ name = this.name, city = this.city, job = this.job } = {}) {
  console.log('My name is ' + name + ' and I come from ' + city + ' and I am a ' + job + '.')
}.bind(defaultOptions)

makeSentence()
makeSentence({ name: 'Michael' })
makeSentence({ name: 'Michael', city: 'London' })
makeSentence({ name: 'Michael', city: 'London', job: 'Programmer' })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function makeSentence(defaultOptions, nameOverride) {
   defaultOptions.name = nameOverride || defaultOptions.name;
   console.log('My name is ' + defaultOptions.name + ' and I come from ' + defaultOptions.city + ' and I am a ' + defaultOptions.job + '.');
 }
```

If you want it more dynamic:

```
 function makeSentence(defaultOptions, property, nameOverride) {

   defaultOptions[property] = nameOverride || defaultOptions[property];
   console.log('My name is ' + defaultOptions.name + ' and I come from ' + defaultOptions.city + ' and I am a ' + defaultOptions.job + '.');
 }

 makeSentence(defaultOptions, 'name', 'Micheal');
```